# winforms not sending mail to gmail with credentials from app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm trying to create a code prototype that can send e-mail to my gmail by referring [SMTPClient - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) with winforms

```
protected void sendMail()
    {



        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com", "Sender", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);


        message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = "test message 1";
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        string userState = "test message1";
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);
        message.Dispose();
    }

private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        String token = (string)e.UserState;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("send cancelled", "Mail status");
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString(), "Mail status");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Message sent", "Mail status");
        }
        mailSent = true;
    }
```

the app.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="xyz@gmail.com">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="xyz@gmail.com" password="app_specific_password" port="467" defaultCredentials="false"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

but when i run the app, it seems that it does not take the credentials from the configuration file.

The exception received states that:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server >> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond >> after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.24.108:467
>
>    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result)
>
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
>
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

P.S.: I have searched and tried to hardcode directly into the code which actually worked but I'm very specific in using app.config instead of those ways

Edit: Please make a note, I've recently added two lines of code as I missed them while posting. But still it doesn't work

Comment: When debugging, what there is in the variables that should contain what is read from the configuration?

Comment: @LiquidCore there are values which I have mentioned in the app.config, but still the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Your title implies that it's being caused by the lack of credentials. However, the **error message** states that it's a connectivity problem (i.e. the server is not responding, or offline, or the network is down, or you are using an invalid server name). If the wrong credentials were being used, you'd get a different error message.

Comment: @Flater thank you, yes I will modify the question now but its a gmail smtp server... even my side network is working... the exception is quite confusing

Comment: The port number is wrong, gmail servers use 465.

Comment: thank you @HansPassant that was a silly misstake. now it says **command unrecognized**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, for making attempts to help me. I got it resolved by removing these lines from the code:

```
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

and changed the `<network/>` in `app.config` as follows

```
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="xyz@gmail.com" password="app_specific_password" port="587" enableSsl="true"/>
```

Then, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You reference to [SMTPClient - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) but in this example function have args[]. How you are giving login and password to your function?

About port: i used port 587 once.

Comment: thats a console based application. I have modified it as per the requirement of winforms. Instead of arg[0], I called it with empty argument constructor which fetches the value from app.config. Please take a look here at [SMTPClient Class - Constructor - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Note**
Be sure to use System.Net.Mail, not the deprecated System.Web.Mail. Doing SSL with System.Web.Mail is a gross mess of hacky extensions.

Whatch out for the port being 587 or 465, check what is the one you need.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: dude, this is hardcoded, and this I have tried it out already (which I have mentioned it already in the question). However after a long battle, I got it resolved, which I'll post it below. Thanks anyway :)